# Syntax error on creating trigger for concat two columns value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger by concat two fields

```
CREATE TRIGGER format_goods_sn
BEFORE INSERT ON tp_goods
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.goods_sn = CONCAT('TP', LPAD(NEW.goods_id, 7, '0'))
END
```

but I got alert said `SET NEW.goods_sn = CONCAT('TP', LPAD(NEW.goods_id, 7, '0'))` has syntax error?

Comment: I don't see any error in your code.  What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

I found that just use single line format (remove 'BEGIN' and 'END') would resolve this issue:

```
CREATE TRIGGER format_goods_sn
BEFORE INSERT ON tp_goods
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.goods_sn = CONCAT('TP', LPAD(NEW.goods_id, 7, '0'))
```